# How can I allow users to input their own values for the current time when programming a clock in python?

Tags: python, clock, turtle-graphics

After being in contact with an apprenticeship recruitment agent, I have been given the task to go away and program my clock. I currently have a working clock however I am still not satisfied as the current time has to be implemented into the program for it to work as a usable clock, whereas I would rather the user be able to do this to make it more user friendly.

I have tried removing where the hours, minutes, and seconds are preset replacing it with the following:

```
hours = input("Set the amount of hours\n")
minutes = input("Set the amount of minutes\n")
seconds = input("Set the amount of seconds\n")
```

However this produces the error:
    'TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly'

It opens the clock with the preset times as planned, however it does not start counting forwards from this time.

```
hours = input("Set the amount of hours\n")
minutes = input("Set the amount of minutes\n")
seconds = input("Set the amount of seconds\n")

#hours=15         
#minutes=5 
#seconds=0  

import time

from turtle import*
setup()
t1 = Turtle()

while True:
        t1.clear()
        t1.write(str(hours).zfill(2) + ":" + str(minutes).zfill(2) + ":" 
+ str(seconds).zfill(2),
                 font=("arial", 60, "bold"))

        seconds = seconds+1
        time.sleep(1)

    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes = minutes+1

    if minutes == 60:
        minutes =0
        hours = hours+1

    if hours ==24:
        seconds=0
        minutes=0
        hours=0
```

Normally I would want the turtle program to open the displaying the time in accordance to how to user inputs it, which it does, however it crashes and does not function as one would expect a basic 24 hr clock to.

Answer (score 1):

When reading input, python interprets anything typed as a string. So `hours = input("Set the ...")` sets hours as a string. This causes problems when trying to add integers (+1) to the strings.

Also, be wary of making a clock in this way; any delay in the program itself will lead to the clock getting more and more out of time.

A little more:

- `minutes += 1` is more pythonic than minutes = minutes + 1
- Try to avoid import *. It imports far more than necessary and can cause confusing conflicts.
- It should also be `set the number of hours`; not `amount of hours`.

Answer (score 0):

The user input from the keyboard is of type string. Since you are performing arithmetic operations on them, you should convert them to integer type as following. Rest of the code looks ok.

```
hours = int(input("Set the amount of hours\n"))
minutes = int(input("Set the amount of minutes\n"))
seconds = int(input("Set the amount of seconds\n"))
```